# Why is the smallest element the minimizer for the square-rooted absolute distance?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I am searching for a minimizer of the function
$$\min_y \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{\sqrt{\lvert \textbf{x}_i - y\rvert}}{n}$$
where **x** is a vector $\in \mathbb{R}$ (see y_true below), and y $\in \mathbb{R}$.



Empirically, I show that the minimizer of the function seems to be $min(\textbf{x})$, or in Python code 1e-9:

```
import numpy as np

# some random data
y_true = np.array([1e-9,1e-9,1e-9,1e-7,1e-6,1e-5,1e-5,1e-5,1e-4])

# testing out minimizers emprically
for y_pred in [1e-9, 1e-9 + 1e-20, 1e-8, 1e-7, 1e-6, 1e-5, 1e-4]:
    print(f'{y_pred}: {np.mean(np.sqrt(np.abs(y_true-np.repeat(y_pred, len(y_true)))))}')

# --> 1e-9 is exactly the minimizer of the square-rooted absolute distance. Why?!
```

I can't get my head around why that would be the case. When I eliminate the square root (resulting in the well known "mean absolute error"), the minimizer is somewhere *between* the values of *y_true*. Yet when I take the square root of this distance, the minimum is *exactly* 1e-9..?

Thank you for some insight on the matter!

PS: Copy-pasting this Python code will make it work in float64, i.e. there are no numerical issues at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't true in general that $y^*$ is equal to $\min_i \mathbf \{ \mathbf x_i\mid 0\leq i\leq n\}$. Define first for notational convenience 
$$f_{\mathbf x}(y) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^n \frac{\sqrt{|\mathbf x_i - y|}}{n}. $$

Now I will give a counter-example to your claim. Let $\mathbf x = (1, 4, 9)^\intercal$, such that $n=2$, and $\mathbf x_0 = 1$, $\mathbf x_1 = 4$, $\mathbf x_2 = 9$. Then you would expect the minimizer to be $1$, but in fact 
$$f_{\mathbf x}(1) = \sqrt{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\approx 2.28 $$
and $$f_{\mathbf x}(4) = \frac12(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}) \approx 1.98.$$

Therefore, $f_{\mathbf x}(4) < f_{\mathbf x}(1)$ in contradiction with your conjecture.

---

As for giving more general insight to $f_{\mathbf x}(y)$, I cannot at this moment. Its behavior is not particularly nice, see for example [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize%20sqrt(abs(1-y))%2F2%20%2B%20sqrt(abs(4-y))%2F2%2Bsqrt(abs(9-y))%2F2). In all the examples I've tried though, it does seem that the minimizer is always exactly one of the elements of $\mathbf x$, and not some number between them. However, that may not always be the case. I haven't given it sufficient thought.

Comment: Perfect, many thanks! That answer is sufficient enough, the Wolfram plot helps a lot. I think it leaves enough of an intuition to understand why the minimizer is an element of **x**, and you showed that it's not always the smallest element. Much appreciated!

Comment: @Doidel It does seem like the minimizer is always an element of $\mathbf x$. It might be explained by the [quasi-convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiconvex_function) behavior of $\sqrt{|z|}$. If it indeed is true, it is also fairly easy to efficiently solve the minimization problem. All you have to do is check all $\mathbf x_i$-values and take the one that minimizes.

Comment: Yes, true. It does seem that way currently. At some point I thought it's the median of a sorted **x**, but a counterexample is e.g. [1e-9,1e-9,1e-9,1e-7,1e-7,1e-6,1e-5,1e-5,1e-5,1e-4], where the minimizer is 1e-9